# IOError while saving images

Tags: python

I am parsing images from a webpage into a specif folder everything goes very well a huge part of the images are parsed into the desired folder then before the process ends until it gives this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\pro\\Downloads\\AAA\\photos\\'
```

The code is something like this:

```
import os
save_path = raw_input("give save path. like '/home/user/dalbums'")
album = raw_input("the name of album: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path,album)

class X:
    def saver(self, info):
        path_name = os.path.join(completeName, 'photos')
        if not os.path.exists(path_name):
            os.makedirs(path_name)
        with open(os.path.join(path_name, info), 'a') as f:
             for i in lo:
                 f.write(lo)
```

If I keep only this part the error goes away but then the images goes to the wrong place:

```
        with open(info, 'a') as f:
             for i in lo:
                 f.write(lo)
```

When i try to use url https://www.google.com i get this error for the same code
InvalidSchema:

No connection adapters were found for 'javascript:void(0)'
[image: Here is the error of my actual code]

Comment: That's not a real folder: check spelling and make sure it is the exact path

Comment: The error message only shows a path to the `photos` folder, shouldn't it have the value of `info` in it? What line of code is the error message referring to?

Comment: @martineau   I added the error of actual code and also my actual code, please a senior if you have any hints to improve/shorten the code itself that would perfect

Comment: Message suggests that an empty string is appended to imgs_folder - I would assume the folder itself exists since you just checked/created it one statement earlier. Check what is at the end of primary_info.txt

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. Try calling `os.path.isdir(imgs_folder)` right before the `with open(os.path.join(imgs_folder, My_imgs.strip()), 'wb') as f:` line to test whether the folder actually exists or not at that point. If it doesn't, `print()` it out.

Comment: @tevemadar there an empty space at the end of the primary_info.txt

Comment: As you write a line-break, it is normal to have an empty line at the end. However if you have multiple empty lines, you may want to print/log data_fetched somewhere. It might be something what ends with a slash (I am a gamer and Steam is full of images having no "filename" in their URL, just the "path-like" component - it may be more typical when images are hosted on some content delivery service, like AWS, and not on the given website)

Comment: When i try to use url https://www.google.com i get this error for the same code
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'javascript:void(0)'

Answer (score 0):

You show different code in your question than that actually cause the error.
This is the relevant code:

```
with open(os.path.join(imgs_folder, My_imgs.strip()), 'wb') as f:
```

Since `My_imgs.strip()` returns an empty string, your file name is an empty string. Therefore, you try to write to directory after join the empty string to a directory name.

Here is where you create `My_imgs`:

```
My_imgs = data_fetched.split('/')[-1].split("?")[0]
```

For debugging you could do:

```
if not My_imgs.strip():
    print('data_fetched:', data_fetched)
```

to see what `data_fetched` actually is.

Comment: Could you clarify a little more what do you mean ?

Comment: NameError: global name 'Urls_list' is not defined

Comment: Make sure `My_imgs` contains more than just whitespace characters.